# f-string giving strange result with uneven width

Tags: python, f-string

I am making a simple function to tell me the length of columns in csv's before I prepare the SQL tables. Anyways I used f-string as I usually do to make it easier to read and to my surprise one row somehow is one char off and I cant figure out why.

Here is the problematic code:

```
def print_longest(source):
    csv_raw = None
    if os.path.isfile(source):
        csv_raw = csv.DictReader(open(source, encoding='utf-8'))

    longest_key = 0
    longests = {}
    for row in csv_raw:
        for k, v in row.items():
            klen = len(k)
            if klen > longest_key:
                longest_key = klen

            vlen = len(v)
            if k not in longests:
                longests[k] = vlen
            elif vlen > longests[k]:
                longests[k] = vlen

    longest_key += 5
    t1 = "Column"
    t2 = "Length"
    print(f"{t1:{longest_key}} | {t2}")
    for k, v in longests.items():
        print(f"{k:{longest_key}} | {v}")
```

And somehow here is the result...

```
Column                              | Lenght
Niveau                             | 1
Code de la CNP v1.0                 | 5
Titres de classes                   | 178
Nom du type d’élément Français      | 34
Description d’élément Français      | 678
```

Here is another csv file:

```
Column                    | Length
CGNDB ID                 | 5
Geographical Name         | 93
Language                  | 22
...
```

It makes no sense to me, why is the second row a different length ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. How is `longests` defined?

Comment: @chepner I added the whole function.

Comment: Still missing the data. Better show the output of `print(longests)`.

Comment: Guess: You've got an unprintable character on the first line of your file, which contributes towards `longest_key` but doesn't actually take up a space on the screen.  Wild guess: That character is a Unicode BOM.

Comment: Here is the data I quoted here https://www.statcan.gc.ca/fr/sujets/norme/cnp/2021/indexV1 or https://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geography/geographical-names-board-canada/about-canadian-geographical-names-database/9180

Comment: Yeah that file you just linked (edit: first link, didn't check second) has the bytes `\xEF\xBB\xBF` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Right before your `print` in the for loop add this :

```
k = k.replace('\ufeff','')
```

**EDIT** :

Or you can specify different encoding :

```
csv_raw = csv.DictReader(open(source, encoding='utf-8-sig'))
```

Instead of :

```
csv_raw = csv.DictReader(open(source, encoding='utf-8'))
```

Comment: Specifying `utf-8-sig` is definitely the cleaner solution.

Comment: Would be good to give more than zero explanation in this answer. Like "\uFEFF is the BOM (byte order mark), which is normally not supposed to be added to UTF-8 files, but for some reason your files have it, and it's getting counted in `len` and printed, but it's an invisible non-display character which doesn't get shown when printed".

Comment: Does `utf-8-sig` break if given files which don't have a BOM? The one nice thing with `.replace` is that most practicing Python devs can be expected to *know* how `.replace(foo, bar)` will behave if the `foo` doesn't appear in the string. But for `utf-8-sig` that knowledge (how will it behave in the absence of a BOM) is tucked away somewhere in the details of how that "encoding" is implemented by Python. On newer versions of Python you can maximize local clarity and unambiguity: `byte_order_mark = '\uFEFF'` and then `if k.startswith(byte_order_mark): k.removeprefix(byte_order_mark)`.

Answer (score 1):

Following your comments the document was indeed encoded in utf-8-sig so I added this to make sure I am opening in the right encoding:

```
def get_encoding_type(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        return chardet.detect(f.read())['encoding']
```

And changed:

```
if os.path.isfile(source):
    csv_raw = csv.DictReader(open(source, encoding='utf-8'))
```

To:

```
if not os.path.isfile(source): return False
csv_raw = csv.DictReader(open(source, encoding=get_encoding_type(source).lower()))
```

Thanks everyone